# How to get friend's list and friend's profile on line api using php or shell script?

Tags: php, shell, line-api

I want to get friends, their profiles and user id to send message through line api on my line account.

Here is the line but I can't understand: https://developers.line.me/in_app_web/api-reference#getting_friend_profiles

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I think you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

LINE API supports user to get the user IDs of users who have added the LINE official account as a friend (followers).

HTTP request
GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/followers/ids

get the user IDs of users who have added the LINE official account as a friend (followers).

HTTP request

```
GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/followers/ids
```

Shell script example

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/followers/ids? \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {channel access token}'
```

Please beware of the feature is available only to verified or premium accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check following links in LINE documentation:

List of followers IDs (followers are friends):
https://devdocs.line.me/en/#get-follower-ids (available only for LINE partners)

User's details:
https://devdocs.line.me/en/#getting-user-profiles